# How to make a jQuery and AJAX call from a url instead of a form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know how to make a jQuery AJAX call from a form, but how do I make it from a link?

I have a list of items on a page and a link to delete each next to the item. How can I make the jQuery AJAX call from the link?

Thanks!

Comment: You add a click event handler to the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to the click handler of the link. Use an attribute of the link to hold your data or use a data-val attribute.

```
<a class="myLink" href="item1">item 1</a>
<a class="myLink" href="item2">item 2</a>


$(".myLink").click(function(event){
    var item = $(this).attr("href").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/delete/" + item,
        type:"POST",
        success: function(data){}
     });


});
```

Comment: Nice thank you! Will accept the answer in 3 min when stack overflow allows me to do that :)